# Chart Js Change Label orientation on x-Axis for Line Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

Similar to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627411/chart-js-change-text-label-orientation-on-ox-axis), I would like to rotate my x-axis labels 90 degrees.
Currently my labels are rotated about 80 degrees with default settings.

[image]

Could somebody help me adapt the bar-chart solution for rotating labels, so that I can use it on line-charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for chartjs 1.X for an answer covering 2.X take a look at the great answer from @tabetomo https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706986/2737978

---

Using the same method as in the previous answer the only thing that needs to changed is the extension of the graph type. This time it is extending the line chart and the set-up is a little different as the Line charts scale is created in the build scale so this time it is `buildScale` is overridden so that the custom scale is used and the new option `overrideRotation` can be passed in. `initialize` is also overridden but only so that the super initialize can be called and get the ball rolling on building the graph.

```js
var helpers = Chart.helpers;
Chart.MyScale = Chart.Scale.extend({
  calculateXLabelRotation: function() {
    //Get the width of each grid by calculating the difference
    //between x offsets between 0 and 1.

    this.ctx.font = this.font;

    var firstWidth = this.ctx.measureText(this.xLabels[0]).width,
      lastWidth = this.ctx.measureText(this.xLabels[this.xLabels.length - 1]).width,
      firstRotated,
      lastRotated;


    this.xScalePaddingRight = lastWidth / 2 + 3;
    this.xScalePaddingLeft = (firstWidth / 2 > this.yLabelWidth + 10) ? firstWidth / 2 : this.yLabelWidth + 10;

    this.xLabelRotation = 0;
    if (this.display) {
      var originalLabelWidth = helpers.longestText(this.ctx, this.font, this.xLabels),
        cosRotation,
        firstRotatedWidth;
      this.xLabelWidth = originalLabelWidth;
      //Allow 3 pixels x2 padding either side for label readability
      var xGridWidth = Math.floor(this.calculateX(1) - this.calculateX(0)) - 6;

      if (this.overrideRotation) {
        this.xLabelRotation = this.overrideRotation;
        cosRotation = Math.cos(helpers.radians(this.xLabelRotation));
        // We're right aligning the text now.
        if (firstRotated + this.fontSize / 2 > this.yLabelWidth + 8) {
          this.xScalePaddingLeft = firstRotated + this.fontSize / 2;
        }
        this.xScalePaddingRight = this.fontSize / 2;
        this.xLabelWidth = cosRotation * originalLabelWidth;
      } else {
        //Max label rotate should be 90 - also act as a loop counter
        while ((this.xLabelWidth > xGridWidth && this.xLabelRotation === 0) || (this.xLabelWidth > xGridWidth && this.xLabelRotation <= 90 && this.xLabelRotation > 0)) {
          cosRotation = Math.cos(helpers.radians(this.xLabelRotation));

          firstRotated = cosRotation * firstWidth;
          lastRotated = cosRotation * lastWidth;

          // We're right aligning the text now.
          if (firstRotated + this.fontSize / 2 > this.yLabelWidth + 8) {
            this.xScalePaddingLeft = firstRotated + this.fontSize / 2;
          }
          this.xScalePaddingRight = this.fontSize / 2;


          this.xLabelRotation++;
          this.xLabelWidth = cosRotation * originalLabelWidth;

        }
      }
      if (this.xLabelRotation > 0) {
        this.endPoint -= Math.sin(helpers.radians(this.xLabelRotation)) * originalLabelWidth + 3;
      }
    } else {
      this.xLabelWidth = 0;
      this.xScalePaddingRight = this.padding;
      this.xScalePaddingLeft = this.padding;
    }

  },

});

Chart.types.Line.extend({
  name: "MyLine",
  initialize: function(data) {
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  buildScale: function(labels) {
    var self = this;

    var dataTotal = function() {
      var values = [];
      self.eachPoints(function(point) {
        values.push(point.value);
      });

      return values;
    };

    var scaleOptions = {
      templateString: this.options.scaleLabel,
      height: this.chart.height,
      width: this.chart.width,
      ctx: this.chart.ctx,
      textColor: this.options.scaleFontColor,
      offsetGridLines: this.options.offsetGridLines,
      fontSize: this.options.scaleFontSize,
      fontStyle: this.options.scaleFontStyle,
      fontFamily: this.options.scaleFontFamily,
      valuesCount: labels.length,
      beginAtZero: this.options.scaleBeginAtZero,
      integersOnly: this.options.scaleIntegersOnly,
      calculateYRange: function(currentHeight) {
        var updatedRanges = helpers.calculateScaleRange(
          dataTotal(),
          currentHeight,
          this.fontSize,
          this.beginAtZero,
          this.integersOnly
        );
        helpers.extend(this, updatedRanges);
      },
      xLabels: labels,
      font: helpers.fontString(this.options.scaleFontSize, this.options.scaleFontStyle, this.options.scaleFontFamily),
      lineWidth: this.options.scaleLineWidth,
      lineColor: this.options.scaleLineColor,
      showHorizontalLines: this.options.scaleShowHorizontalLines,
      showVerticalLines: this.options.scaleShowVerticalLines,
      gridLineWidth: (this.options.scaleShowGridLines) ? this.options.scaleGridLineWidth : 0,
      gridLineColor: (this.options.scaleShowGridLines) ? this.options.scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      padding: (this.options.showScale) ? 0 : this.options.pointDotRadius + this.options.pointDotStrokeWidth,
      showLabels: this.options.scaleShowLabels,
      display: this.options.showScale,
      overrideRotation: this.options.overrideRotation,
    };

    if (this.options.scaleOverride) {
      helpers.extend(scaleOptions, {
        calculateYRange: helpers.noop,
        steps: this.options.scaleSteps,
        stepValue: this.options.scaleStepWidth,
        min: this.options.scaleStartValue,
        max: this.options.scaleStartValue + (this.options.scaleSteps * this.options.scaleStepWidth)
      });
    }


    this.scale = new Chart.MyScale(scaleOptions);
  },
});



var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
};

var barChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(20,20,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(20,20,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(20,20,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(20,20,220,1)",
    data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
  }, {
    fillColor: "rgba(120,120,120,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(120,220,120,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(120,120,120,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(120,120,120,1)",
    data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
  }, {
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
  }]

}
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).MyLine(barChartData, {
    overrideRotation: 90
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" height="150" width="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Quince. Did you notice that in your snippet, when the tooltips are displayed the background color of the legend does not change to the stroke color? If I understand it right they should display `datasets[i].strokeColor`. I noticed this while working with the Chart.js examples.

Comment: @Delcon, sorry it was because I was using the previous example which had the data set up for a bar chart and missed the line chart properties, updated to have actual line chart setup in the data

Answer (score 193):

If you are using chart.js 2.x, just set `maxRotation: 90` and `minRotation: 90` in ticks options. It works for me! And if you want to all x-labels, you may want to set `autoSkip: false`. The following is an example.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false,
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Straight to the config settings I was searching for!

Comment: *** NOTE: for chart.js 3.x the options format changed, so it is necessary to remove the square brackets at lines 6 and 12 above.

Answer (score 26):

It worked for me on version 3.1.0

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 14):

for x axis use this

```
 options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
          ticks: {
                autoSkip: false,
                maxRotation: 0,
                minRotation: 0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

and can filter the label with a `for` loop:

```
      arrayLabels.forEach((date, i) => {
    let label = "";
    if (i % step == 0 && fecha) {
      label = moment(date, "DD/MM").format("DD MMM");
    }
    labels.push(label);
  });
   chartOptions.data.labels = labels;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more hackier version (Quince's answer is better - the following may break if a future implementation of Chart.js does `calculateXLabelRotation` differently)

The label rotation is calculated by progressively rotating the labels so that they fit between the vertical grid lines - the space between them is calculated using `scale.calculateX(1) - scale.calculateX(0)`. We jump in at the right point to force the result of this calculation to be 0 (by making `scale.calculateX` return the same value) - this in turn forces the rotation to progress to it's maximum (i.e. 90 degrees)

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var scale = this.scale;
        var originalCalculateXLabelRotation = scale.calculateXLabelRotation;
        var originalXScalePaddingLeft = scale.xScalePaddingLeft;
        scale.calculateXLabelRotation = function () {
            var originalCalculateX = scale.calculateX;
            scale.calculateX = function () {
                return 0;
            }
            originalCalculateXLabelRotation.apply(this, arguments);
            scale.xScalePaddingLeft = originalXScalePaddingLeft;
            scale.calculateX = originalCalculateX;
        }
        this.scale.fit();
    }
});
```

and then

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gc5gdg7e/