# Tilting the labels of the x axis to some degrees in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, label

I am constructing a chart using chart.js. Is there any simple method to tilt the x axis labels to some degrees? There was a lot of things done to make it tilt in [Chart Js change text label orientation on Ox axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627411/chart-js-change-text-label-orientation-on-ox-axis). Anything simple can be done?

Comment: are you looking for rotating only the x axis or rotating the whole graph would suit you ?

Comment: Only the labels of Xaxis and not the whole Xaxis.

Comment: If you want just 90 degrees check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/35039580/360067. By the way, you can move the extensions from the answer linked into your question into separate file - that would make the code a lot more organized, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Duplicate(?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022830/chart-js-change-label-orientation-on-x-axis-for-line-charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the chart to do this - you override the `calculateXLabelRotation` method of the scale object.

---

**Preview(s)**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
  name: "LineAlt",
  initialize: function() {
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

    var scale = this.scale;
    var chart = this.chart;
    scale.calculateXLabelRotation = function() {
      var originalLabelWidth = Chart.helpers.longestText(chart.ctx, scale.font, scale.xLabels);
      var firstWidth = ctx.measureText(scale.xLabels[0]).width;
      var firstRotated = Math.cos(Chart.helpers.radians(scale.xLabelRotation)) * firstWidth;
      scale.xLabelRotation = 45;
      scale.endPoint -= Math.sin(Chart.helpers.radians(scale.xLabelRotation)) * originalLabelWidth + 3;
      scale.xScalePaddingLeft = firstRotated + scale.fontSize / 2;
    }
    this.scale.fit();
  }
});
```

and then

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vvLttjz4/

Comment: This works, but for some reason my Y axis has disappeared! Any ideas why? :/ If I use **Line**, the Y axis appear, if I use **LineAlt**, it doesn't. I see it appears in your jsfiddle, what confuses me even more.

Comment: Ok, I just needed to update the xScalePaddingLeft line to scale.xScalePaddingLeft = firstRotated + scale.fontSize;