# How to change chartjs ticks orientation to 'slope right'?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there a some way to change to ticks orientation in chartjs to the following:

[image: tick orientation]

I know I can change the rotation with minRotation and maxRotation but I haven't found a way to change the text orientation to the way I've shown in the image.

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min: 0,
    autoSkip: false,
    display: true,
    minRotation: 500,
    maxRotation: 500             
  }
}]
```

Here's [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6m1L3db5/2/) of how I want the text to 'slope right' except that I want to flip the text so that it is actually readable.

**Edit**: I was able to change the ticks orientation with the following options:

```
options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 80
      }
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            reverse: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            autoSkip: false,
            display: true,
            minRotation: 320,
            maxRotation: 320,
            labelOffset: 40
        },
        gridLines:
        {
            tickMarkLength: 60,
            display: false
        },
        display: true,
        maxBarThickness: 50
    }]
  }
}
```

The following setting properties were important here: **minRotation**, **maxRotation**, **padding** (bottom), and **tickMarkLength**.

The problem with these settings is that the ticks will always go like this, and not just when they don't fit horizontally underneath the bars. Here's [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pyLe4x5h/)

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: *The following code applies to* [highcharts](/questions/tagged/highcharts) *only.*

---

Instead of `minRotation` - `maxRotation`, by using "[rotation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.rotation)", you could rotate the labels of the `x-axis` - horizontal labels of the chart.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
    labels: {
      // Set rotation of thex-axis labels to 45°: 
      rotation: 45
    }
  },
```

This [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/yrdcxLnt/) - *which is based on this chart found in the [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent)* - contains the modification using `rotation` property.

I'm not sure why in your sample code I couldn't rotate the labels with `rotation` property, but, you can modify the code provided here for your purposes.

Comment: Hi Marco, your documentation link refers to highcharts, but I am using ChartJS: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/axes/cartesian/

Comment: @randomname56789 you're correct, my bad. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35361987/12511801) or any of the other ones posted there. Good luck. I'll leave this answer - just in case or when you found the solution and post your own answer :)