# How do I override the function convertTicksToLabels chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to be able to map tick values to strings in Chart.js.

In the documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html?h=converttick) I found the function

```
// Transform the ticks array of the scale instance into strings. The default implementation simply calls this.options.ticks.callback(numericalTick, index, ticks);
convertTicksToLabels: function() {}
```

Is there an example of how(like in what format)/where to write this function?

I assume it should be written in the options...Here is my code:

```
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: dataObj,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{ 
                ticks:{display: false},
                gridLines:{display:false}

            }],
            xAxes: [{ 
                ticks:{display: true},
                gridLines:{display:false},
                convertTicksToLabels: function() {//what goes in here?}
            }]
          }
    }
});
```

So far, I have only found answers about [displaying formatted lines on an axis](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2791), which does not use this function, and [overriding the `calculateXLabelRotation` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627411/chart-js-change-text-label-orientation-on-ox-axis), which does not involve mapping strings to tick values (only returning one label rotation).

Answer (score 0):

I found an different way to map values to strings without using the function.

I used the `callback` key instead of the `convertTicksToLabels` function.

Here is my code now...

```
      chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bubble',
        data: dataObj,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{ 
                    ticks:{
                        display: true,
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return mapValtoString(value);
                        }
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {labelString: "Factualness"},
                    gridLines:{display:false}
                }],
                xAxes: [{ 
                    ticks:{display: false},
                    scaleLabel: {labelString: "Bias"},
                    gridLines:{display:false}
                }]
              }
        }
    });
```

The `mapValToString()` function looks like this...

```
function mapValtoString(val){
    switch(val){
        case 1:
            return "LOW";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "MEDIUM";
            break;
        case 3:
            return "HIGH";
            break;  
        default:
            return "";
    }
```

I return the string I want associated with a value and a blank string on the values not needed.

This solved my problem, the graph now displays strings instead of number values.